# Gestures not working in Firefox

Tags: touchpad, laptop, gestures

I've installed the latest and greatest Ubuntu 22.04 but I don't like the following and was wondering if anybody might know how to fix them. No zoom in/out track-pad gestures in Firefox? Not so concerned about the back/forward but  like the simplicity of my laptops track-pads pinch to zoom. It works fine in fedora 36 beta so it's definitely a Ubuntu issue!

Comment: Please limit questions here to one at a time. Feel free to open a new question for 2. Indicate also what you want: not everybody is supposed to know how it is displayed on Mac.

Comment: Check if switching to the apt version of firefox helps. https://askubuntu.com/a/1404401/124466

Answer (score 0):

There is a potential solution you can try:

Open a terminal.
Create a system-wide configuration file for Xsession:

```
sudo nano /etc/X11/Xsession.d/99enable-xinput2
```

Paste the following content in the nano editor:

```
#!/bin/sh
export MOZ_USE_XINPUT2=1
```

Save the file (press Ctrl + O, then Enter) and exit the editor (press Ctrl + X).

Make the script executable:

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/X11/Xsession.d/99enable-xinput2
```

Restart your computer.

To revert changes:

```
sudo rm /etc/X11/Xsession.d/99enable-xinput2
```